# jQuery not child of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <div class="list">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="list">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I have a jQuery instance of a 'wrapper' div, how can I find things in that div, but not in any child 'wrapper' div?

I want to `wrapper.find('.list')` and get the first and third lists, but not the second.  `wrapper.find('.list').not('.wrapper .wrapper *')` seems to work, but not sure if there's something better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```js
var $target = $(".wrapper .list").filter(function(){
  return $(this).parents(".wrapper").length === 1;
});

$target.css("background-color", "coral");
```

```css
div{
  min-height: 10px;
  min-width: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <div class="list"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="list"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  If I have an instance of the outer 'wrapper', I want the first and last 'list's.  If I have an instance of the inner 'wrapper', I want the middle list.

Answer (score 0):

Use selector `:only-child`.

For your example :

```
$('.wrapper:only-child').children('.list');
```

Will only return all the first level '.list' divs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this could solve your problem:

```
$( ".wrapper:first" ).children( ".list" )
```

Where `$( ".wrapper:first" )` would get only the first appearance of .wrapper, and `children( ".list" )` would get only its children

I hope that's what you are looking for